# Create Boundary Layer on FeatureLayer Geotools

Tags: geotools

I want to create a boundary layer on my FeatureLayer in Geotools is there any direct option to create this.
Following Image shows what i want to achieve this.[image]

Please suggest .
we have done this in DotNET by using ConvexHull algorithm .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the spatial smarts of GeoTools is handled by JTS so it's always worth checking there. I would use the JTS [ConvexHull](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/ConvexHull.html) class - it looks to take a `geometry` or `Coordinate` array at construction and has a `getConvexHull()` method. So something like:

```
private Geometry convexHull(SimpleFeatureCollection fc) {
    ArrayList<Geometry> geoms = new ArrayList<>();
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = fc.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
        geoms.add((Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry());
      }
      GeometryCollection geometryCollection = (GeometryCollection) factory.buildGeometry(geoms);

      Geometry g = geometryCollection.union();
      ConvexHull hull = new ConvexHull(g);

      return hull.getConvexHull();
    }
```